# how accurate is the calculation in stm32?

Tags: calculation

I have a project plan in which there are calculations that require high precision, which later will have calculations with numbers after commas such as 245.5431657288. from some of the information that I read to make the project a success it must use 32 bytes, initially I wanted to use arduino due, but for some reasons I was more interested in using STM32 but my knowledge of STM32 is not much, especially in terms of the level of precision calculation, therefore I ask is STM32 suitable for my project? I hope my question can be understood, thank you.

Comment: not an arduino question

Comment: `numbers after commas` ...  do you mean numbers after the decimal point? ... a comma is `,` ... those are called `decimal places` ... `245.5431657288` has 10 decimal places in the fractional part

Comment: you could convert to integer by multiplying ... `245.5431657288` becomes `2455431657288`, which is hexadecimal `23B B321 B748` ... that fits into 43 bits

Comment: There are multiple arduino compatible devices based on STM32 architecture. Understanding the precision of the various CPU offerings is key to making proper design choices. I believe this question is on topic.

Comment: There is an intro to floating point units(fpu) for STM32 MCUs at https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00047230-floating-point-unit-demonstration-on-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: You have to look for a platform that supports double-precision floating point, i.e. 64-bit floats. According to RowanP's link, some STM32 do. Or you could do 64-bit fixed point on any Arduino, but that may not be easy.

Comment: The hardware does not affect the precision. The software affects the precision. The hardware affects the efficiency of processing at different precisions.

Answer (score 5):

The hardware makes no difference to the accuracy of calculations. That is purely down to the software - whether you use single or double precision floats, whether the compiler flags disable double precision to save space (as some 8 bit configurations do), etc.

The choice of hardware only affects the efficiency of the processing at different precisions, such as if there is an FPU, or what precision the FPU can operate at (using precisions outside the range of the FPU will only affect speed not precision).

Both the stm32 and due are ARM based MCUs, so any differences will be down to what additions there are in any specific chip (such as FPU).

Comment: As far as I know, only the AVR compiler by default disables double precision. For other architectures, I would assume that if the hardware has no (or limited) FPU support, the compiler would emit emulation code (as was common for x86 as well, before they included FPUs)

Comment: I just checked the `gcc` for AVR: That compiler has software support for `double`. I'm not sure if the Arduino tool suite uses the `gcc` compiler; however it would be possible to use the `gcc` compiler with Arduino Uno and similar devices instead of the "official" one.

Comment: @MartinRosenau Depending on what version of the core it may have a command line option enabled that forces singe-precision when double is used.